# Bulk inserting/updating people with additional properties

Tags: c#, .net

The below code is either inserting or updating a list of person with a lot of properties of these persons. The code is repeating itself a lot but is working as intended.

Unfortunately making all the types implement a common interface is not an option for me.

```
public void BulkInsertPeople(List<Person> persons, User requestUser)
{ 
    var credentials = new List<Credential>();
    var educations = new List<Education>();
    var addresses = new List<Address>();
    var emails = new List<Email>();
    var phones = new List<Phone>();
    var practitionerDetails = new List<PractitionerDetails>();
    var recruitingInfo = new List<RecruitingInfo>();
    var familyMembers = new List<FamilyMember>();            
    var socialLinks = new List<SocialLink>();
    var employments = new List<Employment>();

     if (_context != null)
    {
         var strategy = _context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();

        strategy.Execute(() =>
        {
            using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                    var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig() { SetOutputIdentity = true, CalculateStats = true, PreserveInsertOrder = true};
                    _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(persons, bulkConfig);


                    foreach (var person in persons)
                    {
                        person.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                        person.CreatedBy = requestUser.FirstName + " " + requestUser.LastName;                                
                        if(requestUser.AccountID.HasValue)
                            person.AccountID = requestUser.AccountID.Value;

                        foreach (var c in person.Credentials)
                        {
                            c.PersonID = person.PersonID; // setting FK to match its linked PK that was generated in DB                                    
                            c.AccountID = person.AccountID;
                            c.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                            c.CreatedBy = requestUser.FirstName + " " + requestUser.LastName;  
                        }

                        credentials.AddRange(person.Credentials);

                        foreach (var e in person.Education)
                        {
                            e.PersonID = person.PersonID; // setting FK to match its linked PK that was generated in DB                                    
                            e.AccountID = person.AccountID;
                            e.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                            e.CreatedBy = requestUser.FirstName + " " + requestUser.LastName;  
                        }

                        educations.AddRange(person.Education);

                        foreach (var a in person.Addresses)
                        {
                            a.PersonID = person.PersonID; // setting FK to match its linked PK that was generated in DB
                            a.AccountID = person.AccountID;
                            a.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                            a.CreatedBy = requestUser.FirstName + " " + requestUser.LastName;  
                        }
                        addresses.AddRange(person.Addresses );

                        foreach (var a in person.Emails)
                        {
                            a.PersonID = person.PersonID; // setting FK to match its linked PK that was generated in DB
                            a.AccountID = person.AccountID;
                            a.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                            a.CreatedBy = requestUser.FirstName + " " + requestUser.LastName;  
                        }

                        emails.AddRange(person.Emails);

                        foreach (var a in person.Phones)
                        {
                            a.PersonID = person.PersonID; // setting FK to match its linked PK that was generated in DB
                            a.AccountID = person.AccountID;
                            a.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                            a.CreatedBy = requestUser.FirstName + " " + requestUser.LastName;  

                        }
                        phones.AddRange(person.Phones);

                        foreach (var a in person.SocialLinks)
                        {
                            a.PersonID = person.PersonID; // setting FK to match its linked PK that was generated in DB
                            a.AccountID = person.AccountID;
                            a.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                            a.CreatedBy = requestUser.FirstName + " " + requestUser.LastName;  

                        }                                                        
                        socialLinks.AddRange(person.SocialLinks);      

                        foreach (var a in person.Employments)
                        {
                            a.PersonID = person.PersonID; // setting FK to match its linked PK that was generated in DB
                            a.AccountID = person.AccountID;
                            a.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                            a.CreatedBy = requestUser.FirstName + " " + requestUser.LastName;  
                        }   
                        employments.AddRange(person.Employments);                    


                        foreach (var a in person.FamilyMembers)
                        {
                            a.PersonID = person.PersonID; // setting FK to match its linked PK that was generated in DB
                            a.AccountID = person.AccountID;
                            a.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                            a.CreatedBy = requestUser.FirstName + " " + requestUser.LastName;  
                        }                   

                        familyMembers.AddRange(person.FamilyMembers);                             

                        person.PractitionerDetails.PersonID = person.PersonID; // setting FK to match its linked PK that was generated in DB
                        person.PractitionerDetails.AccountID = person.AccountID;
                        person.PractitionerDetails.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                        person.PractitionerDetails.CreatedBy = requestUser.FirstName + " " + requestUser.LastName;  
                        practitionerDetails.Add(person.PractitionerDetails); 


                        person.RecruitingInfo.PersonID = person.PersonID; // setting FK to match its linked PK that was generated in DB
                        person.RecruitingInfo.AccountID = person.AccountID;
                        person.RecruitingInfo.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                        person.RecruitingInfo.CreatedBy = requestUser.FirstName + " " + requestUser.LastName;  
                        recruitingInfo.Add(person.RecruitingInfo); 
                    }

                    _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(credentials, bulkConfig);
                    _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(educations, bulkConfig);
                    _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(addresses, bulkConfig);
                    _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(emails,bulkConfig);
                    _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(phones,bulkConfig);
                    _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(socialLinks,bulkConfig);
                    _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(practitionerDetails,bulkConfig);
                    _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(recruitingInfo,bulkConfig);
                    _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(familyMembers,bulkConfig);
                    _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(employments,bulkConfig);


                    transaction.Commit();
            }
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic expression might come in handy here to delegate the repeated code.

```
public static class PersonExtensions {

    public static T Populate<T>(this Person person, Func<Person, T> accessor) {
        T target = accessor(person);
        var type = target.GetType();
        if (target is IEnumerable && type.IsGenericType) {
            var arg = type.GetGenericArguments().First();
            if (typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(arg).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                type = arg;
        }
        Action<object> invoke = person.BuildActionFor(type);

        if (target is IEnumerable collection) {
            foreach (var item in collection) {
                invoke(item);
            }
        } else {
            invoke(target);
        }
        return target;
    }

    private static Action<object> BuildActionFor(this Person person, Type type) {
        //object obj =>
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "obj");
        // T p;
        var variable = Expression.Variable(type, "p");

        var statements = new[] {
            // p = (T)obj;
            Expression.Assign(variable, Expression.Convert(parameter, type)),
            // p.PersonID = person.PersonID;
            Expression.Assign(Expression.Property(variable, "PersonID"), Expression.Constant(person.PersonID)),
            // p.PersonID = person.AccountID;
            Expression.Assign(Expression.Property(variable, "AccountID"), Expression.Constant(person.AccountID)),
            // p.PersonID = person.CreatedDateTim;
            Expression.Assign(Expression.Property(variable, "CreatedDateTime"), Expression.Constant(person.CreatedDateTime)),
            // p.PersonID = person.CreatedBy;
            Expression.Assign(Expression.Property(variable, "CreatedBy"), Expression.Constant(person.CreatedBy)),
        };
        BlockExpression body = Expression.Block(
            new[] { variable },
            statements)
        ;
        // T p => { ... };
        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Action<object>>(body, parameter);
        Action<object> populate = expression.Compile();
        return populate;
    }
}
```

The time stamp and created by are already set on the `person` at the beginning of the loop

```
//...

foreach (var person in persons) {
    person.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    person.CreatedBy = requestUser.FirstName + " " + requestUser.LastName;

//...
```

so there was no need to recreate those values lower down.

It meant that everything needed to populate the other object could be obtained from the already populate `Person` object.

With the extension methods in place, the code refactors to

```
public void BulkInsertPeople(List<Person> persons, User requestUser) {
    var credentials = new List<Credential>();
    var educations = new List<Education>();
    var addresses = new List<Address>();
    var emails = new List<Email>();
    var phones = new List<Phone>();
    var practitionerDetails = new List<PractitionerDetails>();
    var recruitingInfo = new List<RecruitingInfo>();
    var familyMembers = new List<FamilyMember>();
    var socialLinks = new List<SocialLink>();
    var employments = new List<Employment>();

    if (_context != null) {
        var strategy = _context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();

        strategy.Execute(() => {
            using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction()) {
                var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig() { 
                    SetOutputIdentity = true, 
                    CalculateStats = true, 
                    PreserveInsertOrder = true
                };
                _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(persons, bulkConfig);

                foreach (var person in persons) {
                    person.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    person.CreatedBy = requestUser.FirstName + " " + requestUser.LastName;
                    if(requestUser.AccountID.HasValue)
                        person.AccountID = requestUser.AccountID.Value;

                    credentials.AddRange(person.Populate(p => p.Credentials));
                    educations.AddRange(person.Populate(p => p.Education));
                    addresses.AddRange(person.Populate(p => p.Addresses));
                    emails.AddRange(person.Populate(p => p.Emails));
                    phones.AddRange(person.Populate(p => p.Phones));
                    socialLinks.AddRange(person.Populate(p => p.SocialLinks));
                    employments.AddRange(person.Populate(p => p.Employments));
                    familyMembers.AddRange(person.Populate(p => p.FamilyMembers));

                    practitionerDetails.Add(person.Populate(p => p.PractitionerDetails));
                    recruitingInfo.Add(person.Populate(p => p.RecruitingInfo)); 
                }

                _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(credentials, bulkConfig);
                _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(educations, bulkConfig);
                _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(addresses, bulkConfig);
                _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(emails,bulkConfig);
                _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(phones,bulkConfig);
                _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(socialLinks,bulkConfig);
                _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(practitionerDetails,bulkConfig);
                _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(recruitingInfo,bulkConfig);
                _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(familyMembers,bulkConfig);
                _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(employments,bulkConfig);

                transaction.Commit();
            }
       });
    }
}
```